# Data type changing in ArcMap 10.4 Model Builder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.4

I have a simple model constructed in ModelBuilder that takes a Feature Class as an input parameter, then adds and calculates a series of fields based on data from a table that is joined during the model. [image: version 1]

The data type for the input parameter is set as "Feature Class", but once I run the first "Add Field" tool, the data type changes to "Table View or Raster Layer or Raster Catalog Layer or Mosaic Layer". As a result, the Add Join tool will not accept this data as an input because it is the wrong type. I can only get the tool to function properly if I add a Make Feature Layer tool before the Join, which seems like it should not be necessary. [image]

The datatype again reverts back to "Table View or etc." after the Join as well, meaning I have to add an additional Make Feature Layer tool.

Any ideas what is happening here?

The input is definitely a "File Geodatabase Feature Class", so I'm really stumped as to why this is happening.

Comment: Make Feature Layer **is required** on a feature class before a join will work.  If your input is a Layer from ArcMap then it's not needed as you already have a layer, but for a feature class from a gdb you must create a feature layer first.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that is good to know! So after the join, should the data type remain "Feature Layer"? Right now it is still converting back to "Table view or...." which is causing additional problems for me down the road.